# Is there a reliable method under systemd to start cron after all other initialization has been completed?

Tags: systemd, cron

I've used cron for a while; I feel I understand some of its *shortcomings*, and how to work around them. One of these *shortcomings* is that cron is unaware of the status of other services during the boot process; i.e. it may cause issues for a job scheduled with the `@reboot` facility in cron when a service required in that job isn't available yet. I'll call this the *cron `@reboot` issue*.

One *work-around* to resolve this issue is to insert a `sleep` command before the `@reboot` script is started. For example, in the `crontab` entry:

```
@reboot sleep 15; /path/to/script.sh
```

AFAIK, this is common practice for dealing with the *cron @reboot issue*

It has been said that systemd can replace the `@reboot` facility, and offers users greater control during initialization/boot. The "cost" of this improvement is replacing a single line in `crontab` with a unit file and the systemd learning curve. But since the cron service itself is started under systemd (via `/lib/systemd/system/cron.service` on my Raspberry Pi *buster* OS), it seems that cron could be started in such a way that eliminated the *cron `@reboot` issue*. It seems a bit [incongruous](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/incongruous) that under systemd one would need to continue using the `sleep` hack to address the *cron `@reboot` issue*.

I'm still working on my systemd [*merit badge*](https://www.scouting.org/programs/scouts-bsa/advancement-and-awards/merit-badges/), but have the notion that cron should be one of the **last** services initialized. I say this because if cron is the final service in the starting *order*, [it then follows](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-unit-dependencies-and-order/) that all *dependencies* should also be satisfied, and the `sleep` hack in my `@reboot` jobs under cron can be eliminated.

While trying to learn how systemd could be instructed to start cron at or near the end of the initialization sequence, I found an [answer stating `cron.service` can be started as the last & final process](https://superuser.com/a/573761/907399) by inserting the `Type=idle` in `/lib/systemd/system/cron.service`. To test this using a **before-and-after** version of `cron.service` unit file seemed to be a reasonable approach; i.e.:

1. run `systemd-analyze plot > startup_order_noidle.svg`
2. add `Type=idle` to `cron.service`
3. reboot
4. run `systemd-analyze plot > startup_order_idle.svg`

Unfortunately, listing the startup order of services under systemd seems an *inscrutable* exercise. [Using `systemd-analyze` iaw this post seemed to offer an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311440/5395338), but it's not working as I had hoped - the `cron.service` is not always listed. Let me explain:

The *.SVG* file sizes are enormous, and I can't share them, but `startup_order_noidle.svg` did not show `cron.service` anywhere in the listing. OTOH, `startup_order_idle.svg` **did** show `cron.service` on the line following `systemd-logind.service`. IoW, without the `Type=idle` added, `cron.service` doesn't appear - even though it had been started.

To *recap*: Is there a reliable method under systemd to start cron after all other services/devices/targets/etc have been started? Is there a reliable method to verify this?

Comment: It seems that to avoid climbing the hillock that is using systemd timers for your scheduled tasks, you're going to climb the mountain that is screwing around with system services.

Comment: @muru: Maybe... I don't know `systemd` well enough to comment on that. But I'm open to any answers that allow me to start `cron` after the system is "fully initialized".

Answer (score 2):

Generally with unit files you specify the "After=" and "Requires=" flags as you typically have a concrete "requirement" after which the service needs to be loaded.

In your case where you want this to be the absolute last service to load, I would suggest going with the approach of creating your own target, which will load after the currently configured last target (multi-user.target or graphical.target etc.).

In this scenario if new services are installed, they will typically default to a pre-configured target, such as multi-user, thus leaving your cron service as the absolute last one regardless of changes.

Coincidentally the question you linked contains a through description of how to do this: https://superuser.com/a/1543365

Regarding verifying startup order - you can use the command:

`systemctl list-units [-all] [--state=xxx]` *

With states:

- inactive (optional)
- activating
- failed

As part of the pre-start exec in the cron service to print/log all the services that haven't started (or have failed), if the `activating` output is empty (or contains services which you know should start after cron) then you can be assured that cron was indeed the last to start.

Note that this is a workaround for `systemd-analyze plot` since you claim it was unreliable in your use case.

* Additional states are available: `active`, `deactivating`, `dead`, `not-found`. A brief explanation, with some additional sources, can be found here: https://superuser.com/a/896951

Comment: I'll take another look at the answer you linked. It seemed overly arcane compared to the one selected as the correct answer, but perhaps it actually works. But one part of the question isn't answered here is how to verify the starting order.

Comment: @Seamus, I've updated my answer with a workaround for the `systemd-analyze plot` approach to verifying that cron indeed started last. Please note that if it didn't - this will not show the startup order of the not-yet-loaded services.

Comment: I'm confused by your last sentence re *not showing the start order of not-yet-loaded services*. That *sounds like* you will always get a false indication unless you got it right, and started `cron` last? It also sounds like - if you **did** get it right, there will also be no 'not-yet-loaded services'. Sorry for being thick, but this isn't quite clicking.

Comment: @Seamus, Yep, reading it again I guess it is a bit unclear. What I meant was that with this method if cron does startup last - you will see no printout from the `activating` status. If however cron did not start last - you will see other services still in `activating` state. Note that `inactive` will output disabled services, so if you use that state flag you will need to do additional filtration based on your particular setup. As mentioned this will not indicate the order in which things startup, only the state of services in that particular point in time. Hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: Note that the systemd default target after boot may not be always the same, run `systemctl get-default` to get the default target name for your system.